# Save NSDictionary to plist

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, plist, nsdictionary

I am using the code found in this post: [Mulitple Arrays From Plist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6192451/mulitple-arrays-from-plist/6193397#6193397), with the same plist formatting.

This works successfully, however I do not know how to save the created arrays back into a plist, in the same format.

How would I achieve this?

EDIT: It is not so much the saving that I need, but the forming of the data to save.
The plist is an array of dictionaries with strings and their corresponding keys.
All the strings with a certain key are put into an array of their own.

How would I put that array back into the correct positions in the array of dictionaries, ready to save?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Don't forget to create **myPlistFile.plist** and add it in your application resource folder.

```
NSError *error;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

you could scan paths here and search `myPlistFile.plist` using for loop.

```
NSString *plistPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myPlistFile.plist"];
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: plistPath])
{
          NSString *bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myPlistFile" ofType:@"plist"];
          [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:bundle toPath:plistPath error:&error];
}
[myDict writeToFile:plistPath atomically: YES];
```

Comment: i know where i am going to save it, but it's the forming that i need to get right

Comment: @Ashley Technically, bundles are read-only for App Store-targeted applications only. If that’s not the case, an application can write to its bundle.

Comment: It can, but only if the user has admin privileges and the app is not code signed. It's considered bad practice to modify the app bundle.

Comment: @RobKeniger wait, I didn't know this....so I was planning on writing to a plist in the "main bundle," if that's what it's called....so what should I do instead??

Comment: You should store your plist in any of the [various places Apple provides for you to store things](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW4).

Answer (score 25):

Here's the simplest way:

```
NSDictionary* dict = ...;
[dict writeToFile:@"..." atomically:YES];
```

See the documentation for [`-writeToFile:atomically:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDictionary/writeToFile%3aatomically%3a).

Comment: I know that this will save the file, but i don't think this will turn the arrays formed from the Plist back into the same way of array->dictionary->string

Comment: Have you tried it? It can write to a plist anything that can be read from a plist. Unless you've changed the way you order the data in the dictionary, it should write out in exactly the same way.

Comment: **Most important** -
This method recursively validates that all the contained objects are property list objects (instances of `NSData`, `NSDate`, `NSNumber`, `NSString`, `NSArray`, or `NSDictionary`) before writing out the file, and returns `NO` if all the objects are not property list objects, since the resultant file would not be a valid property list.

Comment: This method is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

And conversely, to load a NSDictionary FROM a file:

```
+ (id)dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)path;
```