# Crash on user default reads-really unusual

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsuserdefaults

I have a crash without reason when reading from `NSUserDefaults`. The first time I read it its good . I get the data and its ok. The second time, I get a crash / I get empty value.

Things I have already checked :

- No, I am not erasing it somewhere else.
- No, no one else is calling it at the same time .
- If its nil? It shouldn't be nil, and there is no place that I erase it, and between the first time (has data) and second time(crash), no one is even touching it.
- It saves `NSMutableArray` of `NSData`, it's probably good because it works on first call .

What could it be?

```
return [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"tempImagesArray"];
```

I didn't even put the code to save it, because I save it when first launch the app, second time I dont even save anything, it's there from last time in memory . (It's there on first call not on second)

EDIT::: Assembler I see on crash :

```
0x19f8e2c:  movl   %eax, (%esp)
0x19f8e2f:  calll  0x1bcdfee                 ; symbol stub for: objc_msgSend
0x19f8e34:  jmp    0x19f8e38                 ; -[NSUserDefaults(NSUserDefaults) objectForKey:] + 74
0x19f8e36:  xorl   %eax, %eax
0x19f8e38:  addl   $20, %esp
```

Comment: You can't crash the app with the given code. Your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: see the edit. i was thinking like that but see the log

Comment: First try to fetch that array locally (Remove the return statement) - NSArray *checkArray = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"tempImagesArray"]; NSLog(@"%@",checkArray); What is the outcome?

Comment: once check this one "Check if the key that you use is being used by other libraries in your project".

Comment: i have tried that. its crash in the log.

Comment: standardUserDefaults is an dictionary ?

Comment: @Rant did you succeed in solving this ? I just ran into this problem myself and have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: @NANNAV yeah by defaults it's dictionary.

Comment: Sounds a bit like heap-smashing (a.k.a. "memory corruption"). Try turning on guard malloc.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things came to my mind:

- Are you calling `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]` after setting the array into the Defaults Dictionary?

***Obs.:*** As your code shows an `NSMutableArray`, I'd just point that (according to Apple's [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html)):

> Values returned from NSUserDefaults are immutable, even if you set a mutable object as the value. For example, if you set a mutable string as the value for "MyStringDefault", the string you later retrieve using stringForKey: will be immutable.

- Is the data you're storing too large? I couldn't find a definition of what's actually "too much data" on NSUserDefaults, but I'd guess that if the data set is too large, strange things could happen. Is it possible for you to try something like storing this data in a file? There's a very simple solution in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7198654/how-much-is-too-much-to-store-in-nsuserdefaults).